# Método no devuelve registro

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc

Estoy intentando mostrar registros en mvc cuando se ingresan datos:

Esta es la consulta:

```
public List<ProvidusCuotas> cargarDatosDos(string cuo, string tit){

            List<ProvidusCuotas> salida = new List<ProvidusCuotas>();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("cadena");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("SELECT titulo, nombre,max(Cuota) as cuota " +
                "FROM V_CuetaWeb " +
                "WHERE titulo in ('"+tit+"') OR cuota in ('"+cuo+"') " +
                "GROUP BY titulo, apellido, nombre ORDER BY titulo ASC", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read()){
                float titulo = Convert.ToSingle(dr["titulo"]);
                string nombre = dr["nombre"].ToString();
                float cuota = Convert.ToSingle(dr["cuota"]);
                ProvidusCuotas p = new ProvidusCuotas(titulo, nombre, cuota);
                salida.Add(p);
            }
            conn.Close();
            return salida;
        }
```

Este es el index:

```
public ActionResult Index(string tit, string cuo){
            SQL sql = new SQL();
            List<ProvidusCuotas> lista = sql.cargarDatosDos(tit, cuo);
            return View(lista);
        }
```

Y esta es la vista:

```
<form id="form">
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <p>
                    Título: @Html.TextBox("tit")
                    <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" /><br />
                    Cuota: @Html.TextBox("cuo")
                    <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" /><br />
                </p>
            }
        </div>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                @foreach (var item in Model){
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" abbr="Suscriptor">Suscriptor: </th>
                    <td>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre)</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>Título: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.titulo)</td>
                    <td>Cuota: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.cuota)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Azul","PrintPartialViewToPdf", new { id = item.titulo})
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Rojo", "PrintPartialViewToPdf2", new { id = item.titulo})
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

El problema es que no me muestra ningún registro luego de presionar el botón. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Ya que quitando los parámetros si obtuve una respuesta pues me devolvió registros haciendo la query completa en el string.

Comment: ¿Falla algo?¿Qué falla? ¿El método cargarDatosDos devuelve datos? ¿Hay datos en la base de datos? Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia.

Comment: Hay datos en la base de datos, no falla nada. Simplemente, cuando hago click en el botón no muestra nada.

Comment: return salida; --> ¿Tiene datos o es nulo?

Comment: Me devuelve datos

Comment: Por favor, muestra que que recibe la Vista en la directiva `@Model`. Debería ser `@Model List<ProvidusCuotas>`, es así?

Comment: También indica donde cargas en el ViewBag `ViewBag.CurrentFilter`. Es el mismo CurrentFilter para "tit" y "cuo" ?

Comment: porque usas el IN? si es un valor simple y quieres buscar aproximado deberias usar el LIKE

Comment: Lo tenía así: `@model  IEnumerable<ProviEntity.Models.ProvidusCuotas>`
Lo puse así `@model List<ProviEntity.Models.ProvidusCuotas>`

Comment: Uso el IN porque estoy buscando un valor específico, luego lo cambiaré. @LeandroTuttini

Comment: Ya lo quité al currentFilter @RafaelAcosta

Comment: Pues solo sale el título Model.Count() @RafaelAcosta

Comment: Perdona me faltó la @. Añade esto `<h1>@Model.Count()</h1>` antes del <table border="1">, para comprobar si están llegando registros a la Vista

Comment: No, sale en 0 @RafaelAcosta

Comment: Me parece que es más un error en la consulta, podrías verificar que la conexión a tu base de datos es la correcta? si la consulta te trae resultados después de ejecutarla, intenta depurando el código ...

Comment: Si, verás. Como mencioné en la respuesta de abajo, quité los parámetros y escribí las condiciones del WHERE dentro del string. Al ejecutarlo, la página me trajo el registro.

Comment: pero si buscas algo especifico usa el `=`, seria `WHERE titulo = 'tit' OR cuota = 'cuo' `

Comment: `"WHERE titulo =" +tit+ " OR cuota = "+ cuo  +`
Tú dices así, ¿Verdad? @LeandroTuttini

Comment: en realizad digo algo como la respuesta que agregue, usando parametros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar parametros cuando defines los valores en la query

```
public List<ProvidusCuotas> cargarDatosDos(string cuo, string tit){

    List<ProvidusCuotas> salida = new List<ProvidusCuotas>();
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("cadena"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string query = @"SELECT titulo, nombre, max(Cuota) as cuota
                            FROM V_CuetaWeb
                            WHERE titulo = @tit OR cuota = @cuo
                            GROUP BY titulo, nombre 
                            ORDER BY titulo ASC";

        SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tit", tit);
        comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuo", cuo);

        SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            float titulo = Convert.ToSingle(dr["titulo"]);
            string nombre = dr["nombre"].ToString();
            float cuota = Convert.ToSingle(dr["cuota"]);
            salida.Add(new ProvidusCuotas(titulo, nombre, cuota));
        }
    }

    return salida;
}
```

de esta forma no tendras problemas para pasar los valores del where

Comment: Esta respuesta, me trajo esto como resultado: 

`La consulta con parámetros '(@tit nvarchar(4000),@cuo nvarchar(4000))SELECT titulo, nombre, ' espera el parámetro '@tit', que no se ha proporcionado.`

Comment: asignaste las lineas con el `Parameters.AddWithValue()` ?

Comment: Sí, copié y pegué tu código cambiándole el nombre al método y asignándolo en el controller para corroborar que no fuera un error de typeo mío.

Comment: entonces no puede darte ese mensaje de error haciendo referencia a la no asignacion del parametro

Answer (score 1):

En función de los comentarios a la pregunta, la respuesta es bastante obvia:

El método `public List<ProvidusCuotas> cargarDatosDos(string cuo, string tit)` está devolviendo 0 resultados, por eso no se muestran registros en la Vista.

Comment: Al parametrizar el método, pues no. La verdad es que no devuelve registros. Pero, al realizar la consulta sin parámetros da la casualidad que sí muestra los registros.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo y no intentaste depurar para ver si los parámetros están llegando de forma correcta?

Comment: Sí, pero no sucede nada

Comment: como que intentaste depurar pero no sucede nada ? tienes que poner un breakpoint en `return salida;` y al inspeccionar ver si hay items

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente esta no sea la mejor solución pero pude "reparar" el problema cambiando esta línea de código:

```
"WHERE titulo in ('"+tit+"') OR cuota in ('"+cuo+"') " +
```

por esta:

```
"WHERE titulo ='" +tit+ "' AND cuota = '"+ cuo  + "' "+
```

El método completo se vería así:

```
public List<ProvidusCuotas> cargarDatosDos(float? tit, float? cuo){

            List<ProvidusCuotas> salida = new List<ProvidusCuotas>();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("cadena");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("SELECT titulo, nombre,max(Cuota) as cuota " +
                "FROM V_CuetaWeb " +
                "WHERE titulo ='" +tit+ "' AND cuota = '"+ cuo  + "' "+
                "GROUP BY titulo, apellido, nombre ORDER BY titulo ASC", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read()){
                float titulo = Convert.ToSingle(dr["titulo"]);
                string nombre = dr["nombre"].ToString();
                float cuota = Convert.ToSingle(dr["cuota"]);
                ProvidusCuotas p = new ProvidusCuotas(titulo, nombre, cuota);
                salida.Add(p);
            }
            conn.Close();
            return salida;
        }
```